AC-DC converter resistor identification
This PCB is from the power supply of a standing fan.
The resistor acts like a fuse, having two gold bands in the middle. How can I read it and what is the replacement for it?


Smart - Hi, Unfortunately you were asking multiple questions in one post here. That makes it impossible to link this completely to another post as a duplicate, and it's one of the reasons why posts on SE should be only one question per post. || Therefore, although I'm closing this as a duplicate for the resistor identification, it means you will need to ask the 2nd question about the diode substitution as a new separate question. I have removed that from here. (I know both questions are part of one repair for you, but they are two different questions.)

Smart - (a) Referring to the linked earlier question - as you see, that is asking about the identification of a resistor with the same colour code (brown green gold gold black). The bands which you say are gold in the text look to me to be silver in the photo, but I'm glad you confirmed they are gold as that makes sense. (b) You will need to measure the resistor's dimensions to estimate its wattage (power rating). Any replacement must be a fusible resistor of the correct value & power rating. (c) Check the fusible-resistor tag and search term on this site, for more info
